# How do I query the available base DNs in an OpenLDAP server?

Tags: openldap

If I have multiple branches in my directory (e.g. `dc=me,dc=org`; `dc=you,dc=org`; `dc=them,dc=org`) then how can I query the directory to give me a list of these available base DNs?

Is this a question of access rights, or do I have to give an argument to `ldapsearch`?

Basically I want an `ldapsearch` query that will return a list of DNs that I can then use as a `-b` argument to `ldapsearch`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many servers expose such parameters as attributes of the "root DSE" entry (**null DN**), accessible without any authentication. The available base DNs are listed by the **`namingContexts`** attribute. (Some servers also list additional sysadmin-only DNs in `configContext`.)

Note that you must use **`base`** as the search scope when retrieving the rootDSE entry.

Also note that many servers classify rootDSE contents as "operational" attributes and might not return them in a wildcard search. You should request the attributes you want by name, *or* specify wildcards for both normal (`*`) **and** operational (`+`) attributes.

```
$ ldapsearch -b "" -s base namingContexts

dn:
namingContexts: dc=example,dc=org
namingContexts: dc=child,dc=example,dc=org
```

```
$ ldapsearch -b "" -s base \* +

dn:
structuralObjectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE
configContext: cn=config
namingContexts: dc=example,dc=org
namingContexts: dc=child,dc=example,dc=org
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.1
supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.18
[...]
```

Comment: You may want to see also this post https://serverfault.com/questions/40138/retrieve-operational-attributes-from-openldap to understand the `+` flag.